# TypeScript Modal Window

Tags: javascript

I need to show a Modal in TypeScript. I don't want to use any library(bootstrap,..) to style it, I have to use own less styling for it. what I can use to Create a Modal? it can be a javascript modal that supported by typescript and by all browsers. 
I tried to use showModal() like this:

This is my TypeScript Code:

```
function CreateModal() {
  document.getElementById("myDialog").showModal();
}
```

It gave me this error - showModal is not exists.
even if It works it is not supported in IE and Firefix only works in chrome.

and this is my index.html

```
<script src="scripts/TypeScripts/Modal.js"></script>

<button onclick="CreateModal()">Show dialog</button>
<dialog id="myDialog">This is a dialog window</dialog>
```

I tried to use Onclick as well but it says does not existed.

```
 span.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Too broad, please be more specific and/or provide some code you've tried..

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use [the HTML5 `dialog` element](http://caniuse.com/#feat=dialog) which is not well supported.

Comment: @Mike McCaughan  so what I can use to show modal in TypeScript?

Comment: A library. Asking for a library is off-topic, and you seem to know about at least one of them. You can use any JavaScript-based library with TypeScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're up for doing everything manually, you can place a partially transparent grey DIV over everything on the page, then a single DIV on top of it with your dialog.  Toggle visibility with JS/CSS, and you're able to style any way you like it.

Here's a quick example, with a significant need for improved styling:

```css
div.greyModal {
  opacity: 0.7;
  background-color: grey;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

div.modalContent {
  opacity: 1;
  position: fixed;
  width: 75%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -37.5%;
  height:100px;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 4px black;
  border-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  This is the web page content. <span style="color:red">This is red text     that appears faded when the modalToggle divs are visible</span>
</div>
<div class="greyModal modalToggle">
</div>
<div class="modalContent modalToggle">
  This is the content of my modal dialog
</div>
```

Comment: This isn't really complete enough to answer the question. It'd be better as a comment. You should perhaps post the relevant code necessary to do what you suggest.

Answer (score 4):

I know it's been a few months since this question was asked, but I recently had the same problem and was able to get a solution working.

In the typescript, you can ignore the need for the `HTMLDialogElement` by casting your dialog to type `any`.

```js
openMyDialog() {
    let myDialog:any = <any>document.getElementById("myDialog");
    myDialog.showModal();
}
```

In your HTML, you just attached this function to the angular `(click)`.

```html
<button (click)="openMyDialog()">Open My Dialog</button>
```

The same technique can be used for the dialog's `show()` and `close()` functions.

Comment: `(click)="o...` . is invalid syntax.

Comment: (<any>$("#the_modal_id")).modal("show");
This worked for me. Thank you.